# Is qt-embedded-linux drawing library fixed point?

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, qt4, embedded-linux

I am working on embedded device which does not have Floating Point Unit, I want to port QT-embedded-linux to it. So Please tell me that whether drawing library of qt has fixed-point or not?

Thanks, Sunny.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've used Qt the only floating-point-heavy parts were [The Graphics View Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/graphicsview.html) and [QtOpenGL module](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtopengl.html). Other parts related to graphics mainly used integers, though internally there might be some parts where floating-point arithmetic is used. You should probably have a short look at the source of parts you wanna use.

Comment: Another point where you can run into heavy floating point calculations would be when using QPainterPaths.